# Converting a Google Sheets Filter Formula to Excel 2016

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, excel-2016

I need convert a sheet I built in google sheets to Excel 2016 since my team does not know google sheets. I wrote a formula to check multiple columns and then build a new array from any data in the selected columns. I understand filter is not available in Excel 2016 but unfortunately upgrading is not a viable option for the whole organization.

The formula I need help converting is

```
=sort({iferror(FILTER('3)ReAllocation Holdings'!$D$3:$E,'3)ReAllocation Holdings'!$D$3:$D<>""),{"",""});
iferror(FILTER('3)ReAllocation Holdings'!$F$3:$G,'3)ReAllocation Holdings'!$F$3:$F<>""),{"",""});
iferror(FILTER('3)ReAllocation Holdings'!$H$3:$I,'3)ReAllocation Holdings'!$H$3:$H<>""),{"",""});
iferror(FILTER('3)ReAllocation Holdings'!$J$3:$K,'3)ReAllocation Holdings'!$J$3:$J<>""),{"",""});
iferror(FILTER('3)ReAllocation Holdings'!$L$3:$M,'3)ReAllocation Holdings'!$L$3:$L<>""),{"",""});
iferror(FILTER('3)ReAllocation Holdings'!$N$3:$O,'3)ReAllocation Holdings'!$N$3:$N<>""),{"",""});
iferror(FILTER('3)ReAllocation Holdings'!$P$3:$Q,'3)ReAllocation Holdings'!$P$3:$P<>""),{"",""});
iferror(FILTER('3)ReAllocation Holdings'!$R$3:$S,'3)ReAllocation Holdings'!$R$3:$R<>""),{"",""})
},1,0)
```

The filters checked all 8 columns for data and returned all data in the 8 columns and the column next to it. Then I was sorting the data since I was using an array litteral each column had to provide some data, so the iferror was providing blank,blank if the column was empty and then the sort put those to the bottom.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't really know excel but I know google sheets really well so I'm open to any level of complexity for a solution.

Comment: Note that Excel 2016 doesn't have `SORT` either.

Comment: Neither `FILTER()` as well,

Comment: I understand Filter and Sort are not in Excel 2016, that's why im seeking help to get a formula working that will provide a similar result

Comment: Since you built the sheet, why don't you restructure the data, so it's better usable for your purpose? Also if you provide sample data with expected result you have more chance of somebody willing to look into it. Also attempts of your own (AGGREGATE MMULT) may help the helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get a similar thing as the stacking filter using AGGREGATE it will list all data if the left column contains a value:

(Enter with `ctrl+shift+enter`, copied down and one cell to the right)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D$1:D$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($D$1:$D$5)/($D$1:$D$5<>""),ROW($A1))),
 IFERROR(INDEX(F$1:F$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($F$1:$F$5)/($F$1:$F$5<>""),ROW($A1)-COUNTA($D$1:$D$5))), 
 IFERROR(INDEX(H$1:H$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($H$1:$H$5)/($H$1:$H$5<>""),ROW($A1)-COUNTA($D$1:$D$5,$F$1:$F$5))),
 
 IFERROR(INDEX(J$1:J$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($J$1:$J$5)/($J$1:$J$5<>""),ROW($A1)-COUNTA($D$1:$D$5,$F$1:$F$5,$H$1:$H$5))), 
 IFERROR(INDEX(L$1:L$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($L$1:$L$5)/($L$1:$L$5<>""),ROW($A1)-COUNTA($D$1:$D$5,$F$1:$F$5,$H$1:$H$5,$J$1:$J$5))),
 "")))))
```

[image]

I built it up to column L:L, but from there on you get the idea how the formula repeats and the `COUNTA`-range is stacked.

Also the row numbers need to be adjusted to your needs.

It does not have the SORT functionality, but I believe the reason you sort is to get empty lines your array creates sorted to the back? Anyway. If you want to get the outcome sorted it's better to use these as helper cells and use INDEX/AGGREGATE on the row number from small to large.